# Jupyter notebook: Interactive plot 10x10 grid of squares and colouring based on slider

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization, python-interactive

I have a dataframe that is 365 rows long, each row has up to 4 columns of values. Each value in the dataframe is between 1 and 100.

I would like to plot an interactive graph.
Slider for row number index: 0 to 364
Create a 10 x 10 grid of squares.
Colour the relevant squares associated to the index selected by the slider.

For example if row 1 had values 23 and 55. The slider is set to 1. Then the 
10 x 10 grid of squares should have 23 and 55 coloured.

**How do I create this chart in a jupyter notebook so the render updates when the slider value changes?**

Attached a photo of the df and chart I would like to produce if the slider was set to 1. [Click here for a drawing of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdC6t.jpg)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How do I create the graph explained above? Thanks